# expamding one special node in treeview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treenode

I have a treeview node that I would like to expand just only one special node. I know that by writing `treeView1.ExpandAll()` it will expand all the nodes and sub-nodes. But what I mean is something like this:

[image]

I tried also writhing this command but it has no influence in the tree(!):

```
TreeNode lastNode = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[treeView1.Nodes.Count - 1];
lastNode.Expand();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you manipulate the correct node. In your example `treeView1.Nodes.Count` is 1 (the root node), so

```
TreeNode lastNode = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[treeView1.Nodes.Count - 1];
```

translates to

```
TreeNode lastNode = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0];
```

which is not your intention.

The node "actions" can be retrieved with

```
TreeNode lastNode = treeView1.Nodes[0].LastNode;
```

Second, calling `Expand` is not enough if some of the parent nodes is not expanded. You need to either include [EnsureVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.ensurevisible(v=vs.110).aspx) call like this

```
lastNode.Expand();
lastNode.EnsureVisible();
```

or manually expand the node and all its parents like this (you could also make a function)

```
for (var node = lastNode; node != null; node = node.Parent)
    node.Expand();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not notice that. it was clever mention.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your last node is the really last in your tree maybe - the one without text underneath "Manipulieren (data)". 
What you need is the `Find` Method of the treeview Nodes Collection.

`treeview.Nodes.Find("KeyOfTheNode",includeChildren)`

where `includeChildren` tells the method if it should search top-level only or include subnodes.

BUT: you need to add the nodes with a key value! like this:

`treeview.Nodes.Add("KeyOfTheNode", "TextOfTheNode")`

and keep in mind: `Find(string key, bool searchAllChildren)`returns an array of TreeNodes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think that `TreeNode lastNode = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[treeView1.Nodes.Count - 1];` refers to "actions" not "Manipulieren (data)". right?